# A limit for a sequence. follow up questions about certain sequence.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a series of follow up questions about defining the limit of certain sequence, that I need someone to direct me how to solve them.

the question starts like this: give an example for a sequence $({a_n})_{i=0}^\infty$ by fulfilling the following condition:

$-90 < a_n < -90 + \frac1n $

first part of the questions says that for every appropriate sequence must be a constant limit. and we are asked why?

second part asks us about what the limit must be for every appropriate sequence:

$\lim_{x\to \infty} a_n$ = [___]

and the last part asks about giving and example for an appropriate sequence. (I wrote: $\frac1n -90$, is it a good example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a_n=1/n-90$ is not acceptable, since it is required $a_n<1/n-90$. Something like $a_n=1/(2n)-90$ however...

For 1st and 2nd part, use squeeze theorem...